# jQuery Waypoints not firing with each loop

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery Waypoints to add a class to all .artwork divs when they get to the top of the page. I use this script:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.artwork').each(function() {
        $(this).waypoint(function() {
            $(this).addClass("on");
            console.log("ClassAdded");  
        });
    });
});
```

The console.log is firing but its not adding the class to my divs.

Comment: inside the waypoint function $(this) likely does not correspond to the `.artwork`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're losing your reference to the `.artwork` object from `this` in the inner function.

Modify your code like this

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.artwork').each(function() {
        var art = $(this);
        $(this).waypoint(function() {
            art.addClass("on");
            console.log("ClassAdded");  
        });
    });
});
```